# Manipulate n instance of the same one inner class

Tags: java

I want to make n instance of one class and manipulate its variables. For example I have Class A  that contain variables and i have n
instance of this class with b as an object and c as variable d as
value

```
    A b_1 = new A()
    A b_2 = new A()
    A b_n = new A()
```

I want to make a loop that do this:

```
    for ( int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        b_n.c =d 
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Map` or array. Variable names cannot be constructed dynamically in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You want an array here. Create an array with size `n`:

```
A objects = new A[n];
```

iterate over the array, and initialize each reference to an obect, and set the variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    objects[i] = new A();
    objects[i].setC(b);
}
```

BTW, you should create a `public` getter for the field `c`, instead of accessing it directly. And make the field `private`.

Comment: thanks but i ahve a lot of variables and objects and setC(b) is a setter ? that mean i have to make n setters for stteing the n variables ?

Comment: @user2811139. No, you have to write just a single setter in class `A`. I suggest you to go through the basic Java tutorial from Oracle tutorials.

Comment: @user2811139 Go through this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: yes i know one setter for each variable type in class A thanks

Comment: If you are using an IDE, most of them have built in functionality to generate getters/setters for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array or a Collection of A.

Example with a List:

```
List<A> myAs = new ArrayList<A>();
myAs.add(new A());
...

for(A a: myAs) {
 a.doSomething()
}
```